# counterintuitive truncation of list elements when casting to array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I noticed this counterintuitive behavior of arrays in `numpy`. I have a list of lists that I'd like to cast to an array:

```
>>> a = [['abc', 117858348, 117858388, 'def']]
```

When I cast it to an array, it converts the elements to strings (that's fine) but unexpectedly drops the last digit of the two middle elements:

```
>>> array(a)
array([['abc', '11785834', '11785838', 'def']], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

What's the reason for this? is there a way to not have this behavior? the reason it's convenient to cast list of lists to array is for fast indexing of certain elements. for example if you have a list of indices `x` into the array `a`, you can do `a[x]` to retrieve them. If `a` is a list of lists, you cannot, but instead have to do something like `[a[i] for i in x]`.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well this is interesting running your example gives me this:

```
>>> numpy.asarray([['abc', 117858348, 117858388, 'def']])
array([['abc', '117', '117', 'def']], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

I was curious to see how the conversion works so:

```
>>> help(numpy.asarray)
asarray(a, dtype=None, order=None)
Convert the input to an array.

Parameters
----------
a : array_like
    Input data, in any form that can be converted to an array.  This
    includes lists, lists of tuples, tuples, tuples of tuples, tuples
    of lists and ndarrays.
dtype : data-type, optional
    By default, the data-type is inferred from the input data.
```

it looks the underlying type is `inferred from the input data`, I wonder what that means so I did

```
>>> import inspect
>>> print inspect.getsource(numpy.asarray)
```

we get `return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)` but `numpy.array` is built in so going through the docs at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html we get:

> dtype : data-type, optional
>   The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. This argument can only be used to ‘upcast’ the array. For downcasting, use the .astype(t) method.

well it looks like it upcasts when ever possible, so in my case is upcast to strings of length 3, since thats the longest string I had in the sequence, if i introduced a longer string it would upcast to that, it seems that in my case it didn't properly take into account the length in digits of the other types, this could be a bug, I don't know...

you could just specify a long string sequence

```
>>> numpy.asarray([['abc', 117858348, 117858388, 'defs']], dtype = 'S20')
array([['abc', '117858348', '117858388', 'defs']], 
  dtype='|S20')
```

20 chars seems more than enough, though it may consume more memory, so you can simply set it to the max value...

As far as I can tell `numpy` stores values as homogenous type, this why everything must be a pre determined type when creating the array.

```
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.6.1'

$ python --version
Python 2.6.1

$ uname -a
Darwin 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you use an object array there won't be any truncating. This will also allow you to mix different types and you get all the indexing convince.

```
a = [['abc', 117858348, 117858388, 'def']]
a = array(a, dtype=object)
type(a[0, 0])
# <type str>
type(a[0, 1])
# <type int>
```